# Nivo Slider not loading in Internet Explorer (7,8,9)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nivo-slider

I've been looking around and tried several solutions to my problem and nothing seems to be working. The slider doesn't load on my website when using IE 7,8 and 9. It works fine on Chrome, Firefox and IE10+. There's another Jquery script and a Java script that are on the same page and are working fine. Could I having any compatibility issues?

Here's the html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <img src="images/slide-1.png"  />
            <img src="images/slide-2.png"  />

        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({directionNav: false, controlNav: false, controlNavThumbs: false});});
</script>
```

The css:

```
.nivoSlider {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    max-width: none;
}
.nivo-main-image {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative !important; 
    width: 100% !important;
}

/* If an image is wrapped in a link */
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {

     position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  z-index:6000;
  display:none;
  /*patch IE10*/
  background:white;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0; 
}
/* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
}
.nivo-box {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.nivo-box img { display:block; }

/* Caption styles */
.nivo-caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    z-index:8;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=8);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.nivo-caption p {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
}
.nivo-caption a {
    display:inline !important;
}
.nivo-html-caption {
    display:none;
}
/* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    z-index:9;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-prevNav {
    left:0px;
}
.nivo-nextNav {
    right:0px;
}
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.nivo-controlNav a {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

UPDATE: It seems that when I comment out the lines below for another plugin the nivo slider partially shows up on the website.

```
<ul id="menu" >
<li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('home.html', 'contentarea');" class="home"></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('aboutus.html', 'contentarea');" class="aboutus"></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('newcustomer.html', 'contentarea');" class="newcustomer"></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('electronicordering.html', 'contentarea');" class="electronicordering"></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('links.html', 'contentarea');" class="links"></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('links.html', 'contentarea');" class="forms"></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('contactus.html', 'contentarea');" class="contactus"></a></li>
</ul>
```

So the problem probably has to do with nivo slider in conjunction with this other menu script.

Here's the code for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    /***********************************************
    * Dynamic Ajax Content- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
    * This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
    * Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
    ***********************************************/

    var bustcachevar=1 //bust potential caching of external pages after initial request? (1=yes, 0=no)
    var loadedobjects=""
    var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname
    var bustcacheparameter=""

    function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
        var page_request = false
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
        page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
            try {
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
            } 
            catch (e){
                try{
                    page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                }
                catch (e){}
            }
        }
        else return false
        page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
            loadpage(page_request, containerid)
        }
        if (bustcachevar) //if bust caching of external page
        bustcacheparameter=(url.indexOf("?")!=-1)? "&"+new Date().getTime() : "?"+new Date().getTime()

        page_request.open('GET', url+bustcacheparameter, true)
        page_request.send(null)
    }

    function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
        if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
        document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText
    }

    function loadobjs(){
        if (!document.getElementById)
        return
        for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
            var file=arguments[i]
            var fileref=""
            if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file)==-1){ //Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
                if (file.indexOf(".js")!=-1){ //If object is a js file
                    fileref=document.createElement('script')
                    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
                    fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
                }
                else if (file.indexOf(".css")!=-1){ //If object is a css file
                    fileref=document.createElement("link")
                    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
                    fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
                }
            }
            if (fileref!=""){
                document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
                loadedobjects+=file+" " //Remember this object as being already added to page
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Any advice or guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in document.ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
            directionNav: false, 
            controlNav: false, 
            controlNavThumbs: false
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this solution before and it didn't seem to help. I edited my question to show another clue as to why the slider is not working. This might provide more insight. Thank you! :)